# How to put star rating filter in my wordpress blog website where site visitors can filter various blog articles as per there star ratings

Tags: wordpress, filter, filtering, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

How to put star rating filter in my wordpress blog website where site visitors can filter various blog articles as per there star ratings

I have enabled star rating in my blog where any of my visitors can give rating to every post according to there importance. but how to put star rating filter in my wordpress blog website where site visitors can filter various blog articles or post as per there star ratings.